# Regex pattern to match guid in URI path

Tags: java, regex, apache

I have a SQL guid as REST path param in my request URI. I want to use mod_rewrite, proxypasmatch directives to selectively filter request based URI string and do something else. Problem - my path contains path param,so I need to use a regex to match it.

**
GUID - f4b558edsf443-8bbsrf5359-4cfdgdg67-9a87-5d3b9ef4571d

Basically the guid is a pattern of characters seperated by "-" and can have upper and lower case alphanumeric characters, numbers and "+" or "-".

Regex - .*?([A-Za-z0-9-+]+-[A-Za-z0-9-+]+-[A-Za-z0-9-+]+-[A-Za-z0-9-+]+-[A-Za-z0-9-+]+)

URI - http://example.com/app/api/projects/f4b558e3-8bb9-4c67-9a87-5d3b9ef4571d/command
**

My question is there a better regex pattern to match any no. of such character groups instead of assuming that there will only be 4 or 5 groups?

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
".*?\\p{XDigit}+(-\\p{XDigit}+)+"
```